# How to convert .flv to html5 to use them on iPad?

Tags: html, ipad, flash

I am doing some stuff which requires me to convert .flv into html5 to play flash on my iPad.
Is it possible to do. Any ideas..

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 isn't a video format the format you're looking for is mp4.

As you didn't say which platform you're on, on a linux/mac you can use ffmpeg (from the command line)

```
ffmpeg -i [YOUR FILE] out.mp4
```

For chrome and firefox you should make a webm version

```
ffmpeg -i [YOUR FILE] out.webm
```

Comment: Thank you. Still I need to render them using webview on iPad as they are interactive videos

Comment: so its not a flash video? you can only convert flash video not flash files (.swf)